# How to append the console output to a txt file in Selenium JAVA inside for loop?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void name(String line) throws IOException {
        
          String TestFile = "D:/temp.txt";
          File FC = new File(TestFile);//Created object of java File class.
          FC.createNewFile();//Create file.
          
        
          FileWriter FW = new FileWriter(TestFile);
          BufferedWriter BW = new BufferedWriter(FW);
        
          BW.append(line); 
        
          BW.close();
    }
```

This function overiding the previous line instead of creating new line for **for looping** output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by myself:

```
public static void log(String message) throws IOException { 
              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:/MOV/Working.txt", true), true);
              out.println(message);
              out.close();
            }
```